# How to load DLL generated from python code into VB .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a custom DLL created from Python which have simple functions to do sum/difference. I am trying to call there functions in my VB application but it is not working.

```
Module testfunc
     Public Declare Function do_sum Lib “testfunc.dll” (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
     Public Declare Function do_diff Lib “testfunc.lib” (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
End Module

Module Program
 Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
    Dim result As Double, result2 As Integer

    result = do_sum(12, 34)
    Console.WriteLine("sum = {0}", result)

    result2 = do_diff(129, 34)
    Console.WriteLine("diff = {0}", result2)
End Sub
End Module
```

I have kept the DLL and LIB both in BIN folder. but as soon as I try to run the code I'll get the error
**'Unable to load DLL 'testfunc.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)'**

**Solutions I tried**

1. I tried registering the DLL using regsvr 32 it didn't worked.
2. I tried adding the DLL as a resource from dependency but it is also not working.
3. I tried giving the whole path of the DLL also but got the same error mentioned.

Can anyone help me to understand what can be the issue and how I can resolve this please.

Comment: Use the [DllImport attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-6.0) to define the method prototypes. I don't know what type of DLLs Python produces and how data types translate between Python and .NET, so you need to figure that out by yourself unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to the dll?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows is *extremely* unhelpful in diagnosing issues with library load, as you will get the same error (the one you got) regardless of whether the problem is with the library itself or something else it depends upon.  As a first step, I would recommend that you find a dll dependency analysis tool (I used Dependency Walker) and try to load the dll there.  It should identify the other libraries it's trying (and failing) to load.

Comment: Since this is from Python, I would hypothesize that you need to have one or more Python runtime libraries available, but I'm not familiar so I couldn't say which library or libraries you're missing.

Comment: You do need to make sure that the functions you're trying to call have a C-callable interface in order to use them though `DllImport` or `Declare Function`.